# Catch Block not Handling the error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, try-catch

I am updating and inserting the bulk records from web api(in form of data table) in my table using the Merge statement. The insert and update are working fine but when I am sending a corrupt value.Catch block is not handling that value. Here is my code :

```
 //Creating type to fetch the data table from web api(have to go with this approach only)

    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CustomerType] AS TABLE(
          [Id] [int] NULL,
          [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
          [Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
          [Date] [datetime] NULL
          )

   // Stored proc for update and insert using merge

    CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Customers
          @tblCustomers CustomerType READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN

     BEGIN TRY

          MERGE INTO Customers c1
          USING @tblCustomers c2
          ON c1.CustomerId=c2.Id
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET c1.Name = c2.Name
                ,c1.Country = c2.Country,
                 c1.date  =c2.date
          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT VALUES(c2.Id, c2.Name,c2.date, c2.Country);

    END TRY


    BEGIN CATCH

    //My table for logging the error
    INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG(ERROR_LINE,ERROR_MESSAGE,PROC_NAME)
    VALUES (ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE)

    END CATCH

    END

    Thanks in advance
```

Comment: What makes a corrupt value? SQL is not as restrictive as you give credit. If its dirty data, not happening. Why is there an error catch in the first place? Where is your BEGIN TRAN? Why can you not restrict values in the merge? You are treating SQL as a row by row language...it is relational.

Comment: @clifton_h- I am passing 50 records to the data table and in one record I am passing the date with extra space(2016-  10-15) . My stored procedure is not logging that error in the ERROR_LOG table (used in the catch block). Could you help with some other approach ? I need the error to be inserted into that table.

Comment: Why do you need this in the error log? Would it not be simpler to transform the data that has an incorrectly inserted data? Why do you need to "catch" this insertion error? Fix the source, or make the table robust. Remember, this is a relational table. Verify your data BEFORE you insert it into your tables.

Comment: One method of keeping track of errors would be to run a simple stored proc that records attempted inputs and writes to type error log whenever `CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), @column) > 0` occurs. There are many methods, but you need to understand what SQL is and what it is not. Note you may be dealing with a none-breaking space, so verify the types of errors that occurs in your insertions.

Comment: @clifton_h- Thanks for your response. Just for your understanding let me give some background to you. This stored procedure will be called by a web service and that web service will be hit by DELL BOOMi( ETL tool). I have to send the error that will occur while updating or inserting the data that has been pushed to database by the web service. And I do have to use the try and catch block and needed the error log. I hope   I made it somewhat clear to you. If you need any other information .Please let me know . I am new to sql server. and I was told to follow this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is SQL does not treat errors the way you think it does.

1. SQL Server maintains an ACID state.

**Atomic**: All or nothing. All work is broken into transactional statements, which must be successful or the entire modification/creation is reverted, or **rollback**, to the previous working state. You can be explicit what transaction a work is in by using `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`COMMIT TRANSACTION` or using `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. [Read More: Transaction Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx) and [ROLLBACK TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx)

**Consistent**: Every transaction must leave SQL Server in a state that is valid. For example, while `DROP TABLE MyTable;` may be a valid transaction, if MyTable has dependencies (i.e. `Foreign Key Constraints`), then SQL Server would be left in an inconsistent state and will rollback the transaction to the last consistent state.

**Isolated**: Every transaction occurs in its own time and space. We say **Serialized** to be specific. Isolation allows for multiple, even similar statements to be made at one time on the Server and process every one of them exclusively from each other. The term **Blocking** refers to when a statement is waiting for a transaction to commit and a **Dead Block** is when both transactions are waiting for each other indefinitely.

**Durability**: Unlike a software program that lives in memory and can be lost by a sudden loss of power, SQL Server's transactions are permanent to the disk once committed. This provides finality to a statement. This is also where the LOG file comes in place, since it records what transactions are performed on the database.
[READ MORE: ACID PROPERTIES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480356.aspx)

I mention all of this since your `BEGIN TRY/CATCH` block looks for these issues.

2. Treat your tables as sets of data

Recall SQL is based on the relational set theory. SQL is best when it can perform actions on groups/sets of data/objects. It is completely incompatible with *inheritance*, and using cursive logic is possible, but inefficient at best.
So in your ETL process, treat the data as a whole set.

Instead, by treating your data as a whole set, you can transform the minor misspellings/errors of the user/web interface, and isolate actual errors of datatypes that you wish to catalogue by using the predicate clause (`WHERE`/`HAVING`/`ON`)

An example of what you could do is similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #ETLTable(ID       INT         NOT NULL
                    , Name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                    , Comment   VARCHAR(50) NULL
                    , Country   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                    , Dated     VARCHAR(50));   --implicitly declared as allowing NULL values unless the type denies it

CREATE TABLE #MyTable (ID       INT         NOT NULL
                    , Name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                    , Comment   VARCHAR(50) NULL
                    , Country   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                    , Dated     DATE);

CREATE TABLE #ERROR_TABLE (ObjectID     INT NULL
                         , encrypted    INT
                         , text         VARCHAR(MAX)
                         , start_time   DATETIME2
                         , Table_ID     INT
                         , Table_Name   VARCHAR(50)
                         , Table_Country VARCHAR(50)
                         , Table_Dated   VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE #ACTIONS ( [Action] VARCHAR(50)
                          , [inserted_ID]       int
                          , inserted_Name       VARCHAR(50)
                          , inserted_Country    VARCHAR(50) 
                          , inserted_Date       Date
                          , deleted_ID          int
                          , deleted_Name        VARCHAR(50)
                          , deleted_Country     VARCHAR(50)
                          , deleted_Date        Date)

INSERT INTO #MyTable (ID, Name, Country, Dated)
VALUES (1, 'Mary', 'USA', '12/23/12')
     , (2, 'Julio', 'Mexico', '12/25/12')
     , (3, 'Marx', 'USA', '11/11/12')
     , (4, 'Ann', 'USA', '11/27/12');

INSERT INTO #ETLTable(ID, Name, Country, Comment, Dated)
VALUES (1,'Mary', 'USA', 'Valid Date', '12/23/12')
     , (2,'Julio', 'Mexico', 'Invalid Date', '12-25,12')
     , (3,'Marx', 'USA', 'Valid but incorrect Date', '12-11/25')    --this actually means YY-MM-DD
     , (4,'Ann','USA', 'Not Matching Date', '12-23-12')
     , (5, 'Hillary', 'USA', 'New Entry', '11/24/12');

/*SQL Server is fairly flexible to datatypes entries, so be explicit. 
Note the date highlighted. This will fail your code since it is of datatype DATETIME. CAST is implicit anyways, and should not be depended on in important queries. Theoretically, you could catch this with your TRY/CATCH block, but the entire Merge statement would be rolled back...an expensive and probably unacceptable cost.
  You should proof your INSERTIONS of errors before you start expensive transactions like the MERGE statement. In this example, I knew what dates were being entered and that only the Japanese version might be entered. Dates are very finicky (DATE has no format) and best handled outside the merge statement altogether. */
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID, Name, Country, Comment, ISNULL(TRY_CAST(Dated AS Date), CAST(CONVERT(datetime, Dated, 11) AS DATE) ) AS Dated --TRY_CAST returns a NULL if it cannot succeed and will not fail your query.
              FROM #ETLTable
              WHERE ISDATE(Dated) = 1
              )

MERGE INTO #MyTable TGT
    USING  CTE SRC ON TGT.ID = SRC.ID
                  AND TGT.Name = SRC.Name
WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.Dated > TGT.Dated
    THEN UPDATE SET TGT.Dated = SRC.Dated
                  , TGT.Comment = SRC.Comment
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(ID, Name, Country, Comment, Dated) VALUES (SRC.ID, SRC.Name, SRC.Country, SRC.Comment, SRC.DATED)
    OUTPUT $action AS [Action]
        , inserted.ID
        , inserted.Name
        , inserted.Country
        , inserted.Dated
        , deleted.ID
        , deleted.Name
        , deleted.Country
        , deleted.Dated
    INTO   #Actions;

/* Note, you would have to run this query separately, as it only records active transactions. */
--CREATE PROC MyProject
--AS BEGIN
--WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
--Print 'ME'
--END
;WITH CTE AS (

            SELECT t.objectid, encrypted, text, start_time
            FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t
                INNER JOIN (SELECT object_id FROM sys.procedures 
                            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyProject') ) B ON t.objectid = B.object_id )

INSERT INTO #ERROR_TABLE (ObjectID, encrypted, text, start_time, Table_ID, Table_Name, Table_Country, Table_Dated)
SELECT CTE.objectid, CTE.encrypted, CTE.text, CTE.start_time, B.Table_ID, B.Table_Name, B.Table_Country, B.Table_Dated
FROM CTE
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT ID AS Table_ID
                        , Name AS Table_Name
                        , Country AS Table_Country
                        , Dated AS Table_Dated
              FROM #ETLTable
              WHERE ISDATE(Dated) = 0) B ON 1 = 1

SELECT * FROM #ERROR_TABLE
SELECT * FROM #Actions
SELECT * FROM #MyTable
```

Note that the script does not break anything in the `SQL Server` and in fact separates the bad inputs BEFORE the `Merge` statement.

- Notice the useful information in the `#ERROR_TABLE`. You can actually utilize and make recommendations from this information live. **This is your goal in error catching.**
- As a reminder, understand your `RAISERROR` or `TRY`/`CATCH` will only work on entire transactions...a unit of work. If you need to gracefully allow a Merge statement to fail, fine. But understand that proper ETL **will guarantee such expensive statements never fail**.

So please, no matter what, perform all your ETL processes BEFORE you write to your final tables. This is the point of staging tables...so you can filter out illegal or misspellings in your bulk tables.

To do anything less is to be lazy and unprofessional. Learn the right habits and they will help save you from future disaster.

Comment: Personally, I like to load my data in a staging table and then promote the rows that I can transform properly. You mentioned Bulk Insert, so this has to be data that is cleaned and prepared before you insert into live data. That is why you should be using a staging table (and I hope you have always been discussing thus), so that you are splitting your ETL process into substages to guarantee perfect results in your final database table. Nothing is worse than having to change live data when it should have been handled in chunks beforehand.